# Excel - Decision-Tree Budget / Shopping List

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I'm planning the purchase of a bunch of A/V equipment. There are lots of different options for where we might end up. Some of the equipment is base equipment, we need it no matter what. For some of the equipment we have options to choose between. Some of those choices necessitate other equipment as well.

Right now I'm representing this with a "base equipment" sheet and then several other sheets for the other equipment choices. Each sheet has a total of the base equipment total summed with the unique equipment total from each sheet.

The problem arises in that the base equipment sheet acts sort of like the root node of a decision tree. Each leaf of this decision tree then requires its own sheet, with some sheets referencing other sheets which reference the base equipment sheet.

Is there an elegant way to make a "decision tree budget" with Excel?

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing?  If the tree points to where it's supposed to, there's no circular references, etc., then it is what it is.  It's reflecting where you placed the source data.

Comment: It just feels clunky. I was wondering if there were some better ways to go about it.

Comment: There's an old story about a guy who hated to mow his lawn.  So he let it grow wild.  He stuck little signs next to each weed with its Latin name and called his yard a botanical garden.  You could take the same approach.  Instead of thinking of it as a mess, just call it a network diagram.